# Protocol on deleting an answer

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/953/235).  In view of further information provided by the OP in response to my answer, my answer is irrelevant to the question that the OP really should have asked. He has accepted @phonon's answer already.  I want to delete my answer but want to make sure that this is OK with the powers that be, because my answer has received two upvotes.  I remember reading here that deleting upvoted answers is considered to be inappropriate behavior on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we have a very strict policy on answer deletion, so it's up to you to keep it or not. I don't think that deleting it will serve any great purpose, since another answer has already been accepted and it's quite obvious from the comments that the question has been modified.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I have deleted my an amswer.